# How to set my custom properties to be the very first to be read from the streaming system?

Tags: delphi

I create my own-components, and I have this property:

```
property DefStyleAttr: String read fDefStyleAttr write SetDefStyleAttr;
```

I want that this property to be the very first to be loaded during the component creation. You know when the streaming system loads a form or data module from its form file, it first constructs the form component by calling its constructor, then reads its property values from the form file. It's here where I want that DefStyleAttr the very first to be read.

Comment: Define very first... properties are loaded in order in which they are defined. And ancestor properties will be loaded first in order of inheritance.

Comment: Override the `DefineProperties` method.

Comment: @thanks dalija, it's must be the answer :)

Comment: @VictoriaMarotoSilva you cannot redefine order of properties with `DefineProperties`

Comment: It is against component design principles for your component to care about this. Find a different way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There are some use cases where order might be important. Or should I say having fixed order simplifies implementation. Even VCL has such properties. Not saying that this is generally good thing to do.

Comment: I don't agree. Sorry.

Comment: Generally, components that are sensitive to streaming order should override the `Loaded()` method to delay performing actions that depend on property values until all properties have been streamed in full first.

Comment: i agree, but if the order is working (and it's seam it' working) then if i can economize 100 lines of codes and all complexity that goes with it, why i will avoid it ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Issue with Loaded method is that it is only called if components are streamed. If you create control directly it is never triggered. I would have to dig through my old code, but I remember having similar requirement when I was writing my styling controls. Although, if I remember correctly I only needed few properties loaded in order (as group) and it didn't matter whether they are loaded first or last.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Component properties are loaded (saved) in order in which they are defined. Ancestor properties are loaded first in order of inheritance.

If you have hierarchy of classes like:

```
  TBase = class(TComponent)
  protected
    FFirst: integer;
    FSecond: integer;
  published
    property First: integer read FFirst write FFirst;
    property Second: integer read FSecond write FSecond;
  end;

  TFirstDescendant = class(TBase)
  protected
    FThird: integer;
  published
    property Third: integer read FThird write FThird;
  end;

  TSecondDescendant = class(TFirstDescendant)
  protected
    FFourth: integer;
  published
    property Fourth: integer read FFourth write FFourth;
  end;
```

And you create and stream instance of type `TSecondDescendant` it will look like:

```
object TSecondDescendant
  First = 1
  Second = 2
  Third = 3
  Fourth = 4
end
```

So, if your in your class hierarchy you need `DefStyleAttr` to be the first one, you have to declare it published before all other properties.

For instance if your hierarchy starts with `TBase` you would have to add it before `First`

```
  TBase = class(TComponent)
  ...
  published
    property DefStyleAttr: String read fDefStyleAttr write SetDefStyleAttr;
    property First: integer read FFirst write FFirst;
    property Second: integer read FSecond write FSecond;
  end;

object TSecondDescendant
  DefStyleAttr = 'abc'
  First = 1
  Second = 2
  Third = 3
  Fourth = 4
end
```

However, if your hierarchy starts with `TFirstDescendant` and you have to add `DefStyleAttr` to that class, it will only be streamed after properties of `TBase` class.

```
  TFirstDescendant = class(TBase)
  ...
  published
    property DefStyleAttr: String read fDefStyleAttr write SetDefStyleAttr;
    property Third: integer read FThird write FThird;
  end;

object TSecondDescendant
  First = 1
  Second = 2
  DefStyleAttr = 'abc'
  Third = 3
  Fourth = 4
end
```

---

To address some of concerns when dealing with code that depends on order of streaming properties.

Main issue with such code is that there is no built in (compiler) mechanism that will ensure such code will keep working if someone accidentally change order of published properties, or (highly unlikely) Delphi streaming system some day changes and messes up the order.

If code is documented - places with such properties are clearly marked and if there are unit tests in place that would break if order is changed, then such code is safe to use and is no more or less problematic or fragile than any other code anyone could write.